# Por que me sale este este error "assignment too expression with array type" es una lista doblemente enlazada

Tags: c

```
struct Fecha{
  int dia;
  int mes;
  int anio;
};

struct nodoeventos{
  struct nodoeventos *Antptr;
  char ID[5];
  char Nombre[20];
  char Desc[40];
  struct Fecha fecha;
  struct nodoeventos *Sigptr;
};

typedef struct nodoeventos NodoE;

/**FUNCION CREAR NODO**/
void crear(NodoE **inicioptr,char Id)
{
    NodoE *NuevoPtr;
    NuevoPtr=malloc(sizeof(NodoE));
    if(NuevoPtr!=NULL)
    {
      (NuevoPtr)->Antptr=NULL;
      (NuevoPtr)->ID=Id;
      (NuevoPtr)->Nombre=nombre;
      (NuevoPtr)->Desc=desc;
      (NuevoPtr)->fecha->dia=Dia;
      (NuevoPtr)->fecha->mes=Mes;
      (NuevoPtr)->fecha->anio=Anio;
      (NuevoPtr)->Sigptr=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Memoria llena");
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde te sale el error?

Comment: En la parte (NuevoPtr)->ID=Id;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás definiendo el miembro ID del struct como

```
char ID[5];
```

Cuando usas `NuevoPtr->ID` (sin subíndices) en una expresión, lo que realmente obtienes es **la dirección de memoria del inicio del array**. Como la memoria del array está en una posición fija, simplemente no puedes asignarle un nuevo valor.

Si quieres cambiar valores, tendrás que hacerlo especificando los índices

```
NuevoPtr->ID[0] = id;
```

Si hubieras definido ID como un puntero (`char *ID`) si que podrías asignarle la dirección de memoria a la que apuntaría dicho puntero.

Adicionalmente, estás intentando asignar un `char` a lo que es un array de 5 posiciones. No tiene mucho sentido; normalmente lo que se esperaría es que el valor que asignas fuera de tipo compatible con la variable a la que asignas (aunque, como explico antes, en el caso de arrays ni siquiera aunque fuera del mismo tipo funcionaría).

Por ejemplo, sería más lógico hacer:

```
void crear(NodoE **inicioptr,char id[5]) { // también vale char *id
   ...
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     NuevoPtr->ID[i] = id[i];
   }
}
```

Si los valores son strings terminados en `NULL`(recomendado)

```
strcpy(NuevoPtr->ID, id);
```